# How to align columns in nested HTML using CSS grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I need to use a grid, but my columns are not direct children of the grid. The grid has two columns:

1. Column 1 contains the label.
2. Column 2 contains the input box.

The label column should be as large (but not larger) than the largest column. The input column should use all remaining space. I attempted the following CSS/HTML combo.

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #2222;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 550px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-rows: [a] auto [b] auto [c] auto;
  grid-template-columns: [label] auto [input] 1fr;
  align-items: stretch;
}

label { grid-column-start: label; }
input { grid-column-start: input; }

.a { grid-row-start: a; }
.b { grid-row-start: b; }
.c { grid-row-start: c; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">
    <label>A</label>
    <input>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <label>Label B</label>
    <input>
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    <label>Longest C label</label>
    <input>
  </div>
</div>
```

I understand that the `grid-column-start` isn't used, because the elements are not direct children of the grid. But how can I accomplish this functionality without hardcoding the label width or use Javascript?

Using multiple grids (one per row) would be fine, but I would need to synchronized the widths of the first column. I have read about [subgrids](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/07/css-grid-2/), but it's not implemented by any major browser yet. Do I have other alternatives to solve this issue?

Comment: why you need to use css-grid? this a clear table layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be more suitable for table layout than CSS grid:

```css
* {
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 550px;
  border:1px solid;
}

.container>div {
  display: table-row;
}

label,
input {
  display: table-cell;
  border:1px solid green;
}
label {
  width:5%; /*a small value*/
  white-space:nowrap;
}
input {
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">
    <label>A</label>
    <input>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <label>Label B</label>
    <input>
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    <label>Longest C label</label>
    <input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @hyperdrive add you solution using CSS grid or flexbox if it's possible

Answer (score 1):

If [the browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents) is enough for you, there is the `display: contents` to 'exclude' the wrapper elements from the rendering and only shows their content (similar to `display: none`, none of any other properties will appear on the parent (like background, margin, padding.. etc), but it will keep the child elements in play) -> the children will use the parent's grid layout references to align themself.

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #2222;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 550px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-rows: [a] auto [b] auto [c] auto;
  grid-template-columns: [label] auto [input] 1fr;
  align-items: stretch;
}

label { grid-column-start: label; }
input { grid-column-start: input; }

.a { grid-row-start: a; display: contents; }
.b { grid-row-start: b; display: contents; }
.c { grid-row-start: c; display: contents; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">
    <label>A</label>
    <input>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <label>Label B</label>
    <input>
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    <label>Longest C label</label>
    <input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just want to point out that though `display: contents` may work for simple use cases, it effectively **removes the box** of the element it's set on. this has many implications but as an example: if the container has `display: grid` and the children `display: contents`, you cannot dictate the `height` of the children because they don't have a box! `height` is just one property, but there are many more that fail. it's just something to be aware of as once you add any amount of complexity this solution quickly degrades.

Comment: seems like few things are not needed: `grid-template-rows`  & `grid-row-start` per child & `grid-column-start` for the label... still works the same without them